# Create a window action in a tree, possibly affecting all records

Tags: odoo

I have a tree view listing todo records. I need to add a button that performs an action, such as deleting all entries marked as done, e.g. `clear_completed(cr, uid, ids, context)` (`ids` is not really needed in this case).

I believe this is done through a Window Action (Configuration > Customization > Low Level Objects), but exactly how do you make this action available in the client's form? 
XML solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a wizard to do that.
Selected entries are in `context['active_ids']` variable.
You can take the [account.invoice.confirm wizard](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/7045/account/wizard/account_invoice_state.py#L26) as example. See also the [related XML](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/7045/account/wizard/account_invoice_state_view.xml)

Answer (score 0):

In your .xml file you can inherit tree view of account.invoice and add "button" with type='object'. That button will be displayed in your tree view.
For Example:

```
<button name="clear_completed" string="My Action" type="object"/>
```

Write your logic code in .py file.

Hope it will help you.
Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Arya, but that would repeat the button on every line. I need a "global" button that will affect all lines.